# UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username when creatin a django sign up form

Tags: python, django

I need to create sign up form manually and i can't so if you can help me it will be so kind from you :-)

here it my code with VS code debugger

here  is my error :UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

[image: my code with VS code debugger]

Comment: Add any code / errors as text formatted as code not images. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty straight forward: `UNIQUE constraint failed`

This means `username` can only exist one time (e.g. there cannot be two users with username "yehia_yasser"). If you attempt to create two users with the same username, you'll receive this error.

You've got two options:

1. Change the username of the second user
2. Override the User model and make username not unique

I recommend option 1. :-)